# Query para devolver apenas os registos das ultimas 24h (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query

Olá
Necessitava fazer uma query que me retorna-se os valores de apenas das ultimas 24h

eu tenho a seguinte query:

```
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('inscricoes'); 
            $this->db->where('data <', $date);
            $this->db->where('data >', $date-1);
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

mas está a retornar todos os valores

Comment: Dois Where? é conflito, faça 1 variavel para juntar texto where blablabla e depois `$this->db->where(variavel);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer as últimas 24 horas contando a partir da hora e dia atual, você pode usar a função `strtotime` e subtrair 24 horas da data atual.

Você pode adicionar BETWEEN na sua query:

```
$maxDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$minDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strototime('-24 hours');

$this->db->where(
     "data BETWEEN $minDate AND $maxDate", NULL, FALSE
);
```

Agora se você quer as atividades apenas dentro do dia atual, você pode fazer assim:

```
 $maxDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('now 23:59:59'))

 $minDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('now 00:00:00'));
```

Referência foi tirada da resposta do [Stackoverflow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941658/3096922) e adaptada por mim.